# Conditional step in json-ld how-to pages

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld

I need to create a json-ld block for a HowTo page. Here's a simple example:

```
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "HowTo",
    "name": "How to do something",
    "step": [
        {
            "@type": "HowToStep",
            "name": "step 1",
            "itemListElement": {
                "@type": "HowToDirection",
                "text": "step 1.1"
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "HowToStep",
            "name": "step 2",
            "itemListElement": [
                {
                    "@type": "HowToDirection",
                    "text": "step 2.1"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "HowToDirection",
                    "text": "step 2.2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to do something a bit more more complex. The HowTo page I need to convert contains some conditional steps. Something like:

```
if phone == iPhone:
   step x
   step y
if phone == Samsung:
   step z
   step w
```

Can this kind of conditional structure be implemented using json-ld HowTo schema?

Comment: Why are you ignoring the property https://schema.org/tool ?

Comment: @nikant25 `tool` is not a mandatory field, it seems.

Comment: Yes, you can create it dynamically, as you would any JSON object. Add more information, what data do you have, and how do you want it to look, where would you deploy it and similar